# Racket - lang plai - define-type and type-case explanations

Tags: scheme, racket, plai

Can someone try and explain these two functions: "define-type" and "type-case" in the PLAI scheme in racket? I'm a noob programmer and I don't really understand the documentation on the racket website. If anyone could provide examples, it would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The first page of the Racket documentation for PLAI has a link to the book.

Comment: [2nd edition in html and pdf](http://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the PLAI is designed to accompany an upper-level programming languages course. Kudos to you for tackling this, but you should be aware that this is definitely not the eaisest introduction to programming. An alternative might be [How To Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/index.html) , built by a related crew of excellent characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little example of how to use `define-type` and `type-case`:

```
#lang plai

; A ListOfNumbers are either
; is either an empty list of numbers
; or is constructed to two things a, and, d,
; where a is a number and d is a list of numbers.

(define-type ListOfNumbers
  (Empty)
  (Cons (a number?) (d ListOfNumbers?)))

; construct a list of numbers as an example
(define a-list (Cons 42 (Cons 43 (Empty))))    
a-list   ; prints: (Cons 42 (Cons 43 (Empty)))

(type-case ListOfNumbers a-list
  (Empty ()     "the list is empty")
  (Cons (a d)  (~a "the first number in the list is " a)))
; prints: "the first number in the list is 42"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super experienced with Lisp/Scheme/Racket, but it looks like this question is still unanswered after 5 years, so I'll give it a shot.

First of all, note that not everything is a function. For example, when you use `define` to define a function or some other value, `define` is not acting as a function. A function is something that takes some input, and then returns some output. `define` does not do this. Instead, it changes the environment that you're programming in such a way that a new name exists that can be used to refer to some value.

So for example, in...

```lisp
(define cadr
  (lambda (x)
    (car (cdr x))))
```

... `define` modifies the programing environment so that the function `cadr` now exists. `cadr` is a function (if you invoke it with some input, it will yield some output), but `define` itself is not a function (you're not invoking `define` with some input in order to get some output).

With that distinction hopefully cleared up, `define-type` is not a function. It is similar to `define` in that it modifies the programming environment to make it so that you have new names to refer to certain values. It is used to define a new type, along with some functions the allow you to work with that type.

An example taken from the Racket documentation:

```lisp
> (define-type Shape
    [circle (radius : number)]
    [rectangle (width : number)
               (height : number)])

> (define (area [s : Shape])
    (type-case Shape s
      [circle (r) (* (* r r) 3.14)]
      [rectangle (w h) (* w h)]))

> (area (circle 1))
- number
3.14

> (area (rectangle 2 3))
- number
6
```

Here it defines a new type `Shape` which it says has two variants: `circle` and `rectangle`. It further says that in the case of the `circle` variant, the interesting piece of data is its `radius`, which is a number; and in the `rectangle` variant, there's two pieces of data (or "fields"), which are its `width` and `height` (both numbers).

It then defines a new function `area`, which is expected to take a single input of type `Shape` (the type we just declared earlier). The `type-case` expression is used to specify how to compute the area of a `Shape` depending on which variant we're dealing with. If we're dealing with a `circle` then we can compute the area by squaring the radius and multiplying it by Pi. If we're dealing with a `rectangle`, then we can compute the area by multiplying its width by its height.

Earlier, I said `define-type` is not a function, but by virtue of using it, it defines a new type and a bunch of functions that allow us to work with that type. So what are these new functions it defines? See this example:

```lisp
> (define c (circle 10))

> c
- Shape
(circle 10)

> (circle? c)
- boolean
#t

> (circle-radius c)
- number
10

> (define r (rectangle 2 3))

> (+ (rectangle-width r) (rectangle-height r))
- number
5
```

Here we then use `define` to modify the programming environment so that the name `c` refers to a circle we created with radius 10. `circle?` is a function that automatically got created when we did the `define-type` in the earlier example, and it returns whether or not the `shape` we're dealing with is a `circle` variant (as opposed to a `rectangle` variant). Similar, the `circle-radius`, `rectangle-width` and `rectangle-height` functions were automatically defined for us when we used `define-type`, which allow us to access the fields inside of the data type.